# Reference to figure label in adjustbox

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, adjustbox

```
\begin{figure}
 \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption[bla]
{%
bla ..., fig. \protect\ref{fig:fig1}, ...bla.
  }
\end{minipage}}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figure.png}
\end{adjustbox}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}
```

For some reason the referencing to `\ref{fig.fig1}` does not work inside the caption of `fig.2`

Answer (score 2):

Not discussing your `adjustbox`/`minipage` solution here, [Werner already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977369/reference-to-figure-label-in-adjustbox?noredirect=1#comment17600171_12977369)

> [T]he [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) allows you to specify a `\caption` width (using `\captionsetup{width=<len>}`), rather than including it in an `adjustbox` `minipage` the way you're doing at the moment.

Either way, here is a solution, that does work. Also provided is the usage of `\newenvironment` to make your life a little bit easier.

### [Minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={%
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
 }{
  \caption[Short Caption]{Similar to Figure \ref{fig:fig2}}\label{fig:fig1}
  \end{minipage}
 }
 }
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figure.png}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={%
  \begin{minipage}{\width}
 }{
  \caption[Short Caption]{Similar to Figure \ref{fig:fig1}}\label{fig:fig2}
  \end{minipage}
 }
 }
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figure.png}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### MWE II

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{adjustboxwithstuff}[1]{\begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\minipage{\width}}{#1\endminipage}}}{\end{adjustbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustboxwithstuff}{\caption[Short Caption]{Similar to Figure \ref{fig:fig2}}\label{fig:fig1}}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{figure.png}
    \end{adjustboxwithstuff}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustboxwithstuff}{\caption[Short Caption]{Similar to Figure \ref{fig:fig1}}\label{fig:fig2}}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{figure.png}
    \end{adjustboxwithstuff}
\end{figure}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) allows you to specify a `\caption` width (using `\captionsetup{width=<len>}`), rather than including it in an `adjustbox`-`minipage` the way you're doing at the moment. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe
  \caption{\protect\lipsum*[66]}
\end{figure}
\captionsetup{width=.7\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe
  \caption{\protect\lipsum*[66]}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```